# Use Windows Installer DLL file outside the Windows Installer context

Tags: dll, properties, windows-installer, custom-action

In a Windows Installer custom action a DLL file is called which receives data from the Setup using the `MsiGetProperty` function.

Is it possible to use such a DLL file outside a Windows Installer Setup? If it is, how can I set the properties/data a certain function of the DLL file needs?

Comment: You can run a DLL function externally like so:

Rundll32.exe DLL_NAME,Entry_Point Optional_Argument

However I would suggest it's not possible to get/set Windows Installer properties this way, since you'd be running it outside the context of the current Windows Installer session: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371675(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need the right expectations. Unless you have an Installer handle, which you receive when called in the context of an Installer, many of the Windows Installer APIs, including MsiGetProperty, cannot be used.

Depending on your exact needs, I would suggest splitting your implementation into three functions. One is the core implementation. Any values you currently retrieve with MsiGetProperty could be arguments to this function. Any logging should be done through a helper that you can configure to use alternate means, etc. This function need not be exported by your DLL.

The other two functions should then be fairly thin wrappers around this function. They get the values in whichever way makes sense for how they are invoked, and pass them to the core implementation. These two functions are exported.

Then call the appropriate function for your usage, and the bulk of your DLL can be easily shared across both custom action and non-custom action invocations.